# JavaScript array problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

This bit of code doesn't seem to work.

```
for(var b = 0; b < wallPoints.length-1; b++)  
{  
    wallPoints[b].xPos = wallPoints[b]-1;  
}  

function Point(x,y)  
{  
    this.xPos = x;  
    this.yPos = y;  
}
```

`wallPoints` is an array of Points

The code doesn't return any errors, it just makes all my code stop executing. This is my first time using JavaScript, so this is probably a very stupid mistake.

Comment: check this line `wallPoints[b].xPos = wallPoints[b]-1;  `

Comment: Show the code for `wallPoints` please.

Comment: 'wallPoints = new Array();  wallPoints[0] = new Point(0,10);  
wallPoints[1] = new Point(600,10);  
wallPoints[2] = new Point(650,10);'

Comment: A current best-practice way to initialize that array: `var wallPoints = [new Point(0,10), new Point(600,10), new Point(650,10)];`

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do -- shift each point by one in the x axis?  You need to reference the property on the right hand side of the assignment as well.

```
for(var b = 0; b < wallPoints.length; b++)   
{   
    wallPoints[b].xPos = wallPoints[b].xPos - 1;   
}
```

or do you want to propagate the x axis from one point to another

```
for(var b = 1; b < wallPoints.length; b++)   
{   
    wallPoints[b].xPos = wallPoints[b-1].xPos;   
}
```

In the latter case, you'll need to figure out what to do with the first point.  Note the change in the termination condition (and start condition in the second case).

**EDIT**: Here's my test code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Point</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var wallPoints = new Array();
    wallPoints[0] = new Point(0,10);
    wallPoints[1] = new Point(600,10);
    wallPoints[2] = new Point(650,10);

    var content = $('#content');

    content.append('<h2>Before</h2>');

    for(var b = 0; b < wallPoints.length; b++)
    {
        content.append('<p> x = ' + wallPoints[b].xPos + ', y = ' + wallPoints[b].yPos + '</p>' );
        wallPoints[b].xPos = wallPoints[b].xPos-1;
    }
    content.append('<h2>After</h2>');

    for(var b = 0; b < wallPoints.length; b++)
    {
        content.append('<p> x = ' + wallPoints[b].xPos + ', y = ' + wallPoints[b].yPos + '</p>' );
    }

    function Point(x,y)
    {
        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, that is what I originally had in my code but I messed up when typing it in here. The code still does not work.

Comment: @Daniel: It's best to post *real code* that you've run as written and experienced the problem. Code you've retyped might not exhibit the same problem. It also might have other problems, as this answer shows.

Comment: @daniel -- I've tested the code (with a few additions so that I could see that it's working) above and it seems to be ok.  Does firefox/firebug show you anything in the console?  If you don't have firefox/firebug, you really ought to get them.  It will be a tremendous help in debugging javascript problems.

Comment: @tvanfosson ~ I think you've invested more time in his problem than he has.

Comment: @drachenstern -- cut and paste, cut and paste.  It helps to have a template test document already set up.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning an X variable equal to a point. Not an option:

```
for(var b = 0; b < wallPoints.length-1; b++)  
{  
    wallPoints[b].xPos = wallPoints[b]-1;  
}
```

instead try this:

```
for(var b = 0; b < wallPoints.length-1; b++)  
{  
    wallPoints[b].xPos = wallPoints[b].xPos - 1;
}
```